# Get Scheduled Tasks (cronjob) log error

Tags: cron, ubuntu-14.04, plesk

I use Scheduled Tasks in my plesk panel with this line :
(OVH server with Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS and Plesk version 12.0.18)

```
wget -O - "http://example.com/application/lite.php?module=ultimatenews&name=task"
```

but I have notified by this error :

> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
>   ERROR 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable.

How I can have more details of this error ? you have an idea where the problem may come ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find all errors in `error_log` of example.com in Plesk GUI or in

```
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/logs/
```

Comment: There is no separate file for cronjob errors. I've assume that error 503 related to site, and all site errors are logged into error_log file.